# Salesforce Communties : Home Page : headerSearchLeftRoundedCorner{display : none;}

Tags: css

We are getting css tags after user has logged into Salesforce.

headerSearchLeftRoundedCorner{display : none;}

[image]

Comment: is it a vf page? or standard page?

Comment: Its a standard page

Comment: if it a standard page then i guess nly salesforce support can help you